# Why doesn't node.js Express framework use a callback when setting a session variable?

Tags: node.js, session, callback, express

I have noticed that in order to store a value into the session you simply call 
    req.session.key = value
without the need to specify a callback. I have set mysql as my session storage adapter using the connect-mysql module. So I am wondering that consider each time I save a value to the session it is being updated in the db, shouldn't there be a callback associated with this? Yet everywhere I look people are happily using it synchronously. Can someone please explain why this is the case? THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`session` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) only actually interacts with the data-store twice per request, rather than immediately with each change:

1. With `Store#get()` to retrieve the `Session` in bulk at the start of a request. ([source](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.4.2/lib/middleware/session.js#L298-327))
2. With `Store#set()` (via [`Session#save()`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.4.2/lib/middleware/session/session.js#L62-65)) to persist the `Session` in bulk at the end of the request. ([source](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.4.2/lib/middleware/session.js#L267-277))

Between these steps, changes to the `session` can be done synchronously. They just should be done before `res.end()` or similar (`res.render()`, `res.json()`, etc.) is called.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense.